# Import namespaced class specifically

Tags: typescript, syntax, tsc, typescript-typings

I have a namespace set up like this:

```
export namespace Entities {

    export class Car { }

    export class Motorbike { }

}
```

In another class, I then import `Car` and `Motorbike`. However, I am unable to import them succinctly. If I try to import them like this:

```
import { Entities.Car as Car, Entities.Motorbike as Motorbike } from "./somefile.ts";
```

I get this error (on the `.` after `Entities`):

> ',' expected.

I am able to do this:

```
// import whole namespace
import { Entities } from "./somefile.ts";

// use the type directly:
let vehicle: Entities.Car;
```

However ideally I would be able to import them without manually importing the namespace. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to use a namespace in this situation. You have several options here:

- Define your classes in a global declaration file. You can then use your types directly in your program, without having to import them.

  ```
  // index.d.ts
  declare class Car {
    someProperty: any
  }

  // app.ts
  let theCar: Car
  theCar.someProperty
  ```
- Define your classes in a module declaration file. You'll have to then import the specific types you want to use.

  ```
  // index.d.ts
  export class Car {
    someProperty: any
  }

  // app.ts
  import { Car } from './index'
  let theCar: Car
  theCar.someProperty
  ```